# значение типа "const char *" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "char *"

Tags: c++, char, инициализация, const

я студент университета. Преподаватель прислал код для ознакомления. Я скопировал код в Visual Studio 2019 в точности, как было написано в документе, но компилятор выдаёт много ошибок. Я спрашивал, почему код не работает, но преподаватель сам не понимал этого и предложил поэкспериментировать. Уже 2 часа пытался изменить фрагмент кода, а ошибки те же. В основном компилятор ошибочно воспринимает слово за строковую константу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать в таком случае

```
#include<cstring> 
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;
struct spisoc {
char *name; // название книги
char *author; // имя автора
int year; // год издания
spisoc *next; // указатель на следующую структуру в списке
};
  // определение массива структур для дополнения с инициализацией//
spisoc stm[] =
{ { "TurboPascal" , "Фаронов В.В.", 2018 },
{ "TurboC++" , "Винер Р.С.", 1991 },
{ "C-C++", "Березин Б.И. " , 2016 } };
spisoc *s;// определение внешнего указателя на вершину списка, он по умолчанию инициирован нулем (null)
```

Comment: *"преподаватель сам не понимал этого и предложил поэкспериментировать"* - с такими преподавателями далеко не уедите

Comment: нормальный преподаватель. Плохой бы сказал "поставь именно такую студию/компилятор как у меня и не рыпайся"

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что ошибочно? Можете стереть cv простым приведением к (char *)

Comment: не нужно "стирать const" у константной строки. много чего может интересного случится

Comment: Это же C++ используй std::string и std::list.
@KoVadim ничего интересного, просто краш при попытке изменить ридонли страницы памяти.

Comment: может быть креш. а может и много чего другого случится. Но раньше в студии это было разрешено, как не странно и работало как нужно